# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getdlopenflags' on tensorflow on windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I have followed instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) and completed the installation for `tensorflow` 
but when I validate my installation using `import tensorflow as tf`

[image: Terminal window shouting erros]

Comment: Try updating Numpy! Also what commands did you use to install it?

Comment: hi thanks for replying what version should i update? i used "pip install numpy" to install it

Comment: Update it to the newest!

Comment: yes my numpy is already up to date

Comment: And please never post a screenshot of a window, always try to paste the output here from your window. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help about asking questions.

Comment: oh sorry about that im still new to ask questions in here

Comment: The `sys` module has an attribute called `getdlopenflags`, I used it and it returns an integer, idk why it's behaving like this. I believe it's a windows issue or something. Try using Python3 for it.

Comment: From the instructions you linked to: "TensorFlow supports Python 3.5.x and 3.6.x on Windows".  I would recommend upgrading to Python 3.

Comment: it finally work! :D i have to uninstall the old python and install 3.5.2
and uninstall the tensorflow and install it again and it work! THANKS! :D